# Why is my progress bar not centered vertically?

Tags: android, layout, view, alignment

I have the following layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/bg_generic_portrait">
  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/issue_list_item_background_normal"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/issue_background_selector"
            android:divider="@drawable/separator"
    >
  </ListView>
  <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/preloader"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"/>

  <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like this...https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra5c6.png

**I want the preloader to be centered vertically too, what is wrong?**

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"  <--- try setting that to fill_parent

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Somehow the layout_gravity does not work well.
What you need to do is nest the progress_bar in a linear_layout and set the gravity of that layout to center, like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center">
<ProgressBar
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/preloader"
          style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I do not suggest setting the gravity to the topmost linear layout because you could have funny things happening if you change the list or add something.

Comment: Don't forget to make FrameLayout as parent layout, else other sibling Layouts will be hidden

Answer (score 1):

thats because you are using a `LinearLayout`, I suggest that you use a `RelativeLayout`
and have the attibute center using `layout_centerVertical` like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/preloader"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems some problem with what you are trying to do. ListView on top of progress bar in your layout can have a variable height depending on its contents. So, it's not possible to ensure progress bar stays in center of screen using linear layout.

You may want to look at [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)  class that will show a progress dialog while you load data into list in background.

Alternatively, you can make ProgressBar and ListView overlap by using RelativeLayout as top level layout and specify `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` attribute for ProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much space is your `Listview` taking, but you might want to use a `<RelativeLayout>` instead of `<LinearLayout>` if you want to really define where you want `x` item.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:gravity="center"` in your parent LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: note that using that would even make the list be centered in the layout.